# How can I work productively with value objects for a REST API on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest

JSON REST APIs that are non-trivial in size require me to serialize and use the data in the form of value objects for interaction, so currently I either:

- Manually write value objects
- Use a value object generator like JSON Accelerator

Manually writing the value objects has the drawback of having low productivity as well as having to go back to the code each time something changes. There are mappers that can be used for data binding, but I feel they get in the way too much in order to make sense like, JSONModel, ObjectMapper etc.

Generators that infer the Objective-C model on the other hand seem to be very brittle and produce code that is substandard (i.e. deliver NSNumber where you'd expect NSString, which can be a major source of crashes).

What is a good way to have top productivity while maintaining a good level of code quality.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Mantle (https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) ? 
You can define the properties values of the type you expect:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSURL *URL;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSURL *HTMLURL;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSNumber *number;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) GHIssueState state;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *reporterLogin;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) GHUser *assignee;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSDate *updatedAt;
```

And then you can tell which property is matched in this method JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey, like this:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{
        @"URL": @"url",
        @"HTMLURL": @"html_url",
        @"number": @"number",
        @"state": @"state",
        @"reporterLogin": @"user.login",
        @"assignee": @"assignee",
        @"updatedAt": @"updated_at"
    };
```

Make sure that your object is a subclass of MTLModel and conforms with MTLJSONSerializing protocol, like this:

```
@interface GHIssue : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>
```

Comment: I haven't tried it. But from scanning the Github page I can see how Mantle is a better mapper than JSONModel. The thing is, that it is still essentially just a mapper. I will definitely have a go at it though, thanks!